# MYSQL Get Month before

Tags: mysql

When I use interval 1 I got an error in my SQL syntax. I want to get month now -1 to have a month before.

```
SELECT 
      catalog.code, 
      catalog.supplier,
      catalog.created_at
FROM  catalog 
WHERE MONTH(catalog.created_at) = month(NOW()) - INTERVAL 1
AND   YEAR(catalog.created_at) = year(NOW())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put your interval for the "NOW()" and specify the type of interval (day, month, year, ...) :

```
MONTH(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

Answer (score 1):

Kindly try the following code :

```
SELECT 

            catalog.code, 
            catalog.supplier,
            catalog.created_at

       FROM catalog
        WHERE MONTH(catalog.created_at) = month(NOW()- INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
        AND YEAR(catalog.created_at) = year(NOW());
```

Tried and tested in SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2f8d3/1/0
Hope this helps !!
Regards.